# Form submit from wordpress plugin

Tags: plugins, forms

Seasoned dev, but new to wordpress development - becoming a fan very quickly.

I'm knocking up my first wordpress plugin (custom contact form for client, none of the plugins can do the jazz I need).

I can't work out how to submit the form and grab the data. Heres what I've got so far:

```
function cafesignup_function() {

    $x = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    $pageRef = basename($x['path']);

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $name = $_POST['companyName'];
        $demolp_output = $name;

    } else {


    $greeetingText = "<h1>" . getTitle($pageRef) . " Quote Form</h1>";

    $demolp_output = "<div class='mtool ccupform'></div> <div class='greeting-text'><p>" . $greeetingText . "</p></div><div class='maintext'> <div class='errortext'> </div><small>Fields with a * are required fields.</small>";
    $demolp_output .= "<form name='quoteForm' id='quoteForm' method='post' action='/request-a-quote' >";
    $demolp_output .= "<p>Contact Name*<br />";
    $demolp_output .= "<input type='text' class='validate bjp-contact' name='companyName' id='cafeCompanyName' value='' size='40' class=''></p>";

    $demolp_output .= "<p>Business name if Applicable<br />";
    $demolp_output .= "<input type='text' class='validate bjp-contact' id='cafeFirstname' value='' size='40' class=''></p>";

    $demolp_output .= "<p>Telephone including STD*<br />";
    $demolp_output .= "<input type='text' class='validate bjp-contact' id='cafeSurname' value='' size='40' class=''></p>";

    $demolp_output .= "<p>Email Address*<br />";
    $demolp_output .= "<input type='text' class='validate vemail bjp-contact' id='cafeEmailAddress' value='' size='40' class=''></p>";

    $demolp_output .= "<p> <div class='pull-right'><span onclick='clear();' id='cafeAdd2' class='btnN'>Clear</span> &NonBreakingSpace;<span onclick='addUser();' id='cafeAdd2' class='btnY'>Submit</span></center></p>";

    $demolp_output .= "</div>";

    $demolp_output .= "</form>";

    }

    return $demolp_output;
}
```

When I submit that (using jquery for the submit, as below) it fires the submit, but it shows the fro again (also I can't work out what to put as the action on the form to reuse the plugin elsewhere).

```
function addUser(){
    var emailvalidates = true;
jQuery( ".validate" ).each(function() {
    if(jQuery(this).val() == ""){
        validates = false;
        alert("missing fields");
    } else {
        $('#quoteForm').submit();
    }
});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`var_dump()` your `$_POST`, there will never be a `['submit']`.
You don't have something like:

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" />
```

That is basic HTML ;)

And read more about MVC and putting your HTML-Code in another file.
Putting them in strings is something you won't like in the future! It becomes unreadable and unmaintainable some day.

Comment: I'm doing the submit through javascript. It's a one job script, theres no reason for me to breakout the markup.

Comment: Okay. Let me do it for you:

    ob_start();
    require 'cafesignup_function.phtml';
    $demolp_output = ob_get_clean();

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think this article can help you make a page settings in Wordpress:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-settings-page-for-your-wordpress-theme--wp-20091

Hope that helps.

Comment: Not particularly...as I'm not looking to create a wordpress settings page. I'm trying to catch the submit of a form..

Comment: Yeah, there is a good topic about create form in admin page and I thought it can help you. Anyway, did you try to use hook 'admin_init' ? I think this way can get data that form submitted: add_action( 'admin_init', 'cafesignup_function' );